# Problems with fgets function

Tags: c, fgets

Here I use fgets() to get user input with several strings, it never appeared in the output:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char color[20];
    char pluraNoun[20];
    char celebrity[20];

    printf("Enter a color: ");
    scanf("%s", color);
    printf("Enter a plural noun: ");
    scanf("%s", pluraNoun);
    printf("Enter a celebrity: ");

    fgets(celebrity, 20, stdin);

    printf("Roses are %s\n", color);
    printf("%s are blue\n", pluraNoun);
    printf("I love %s\n", celebrity);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Avoid using `fgets()` and `scanf()` together.  Use only `fgets()` until you know why `scanf()` is bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix `scanf()` and `fgets()` or as man page says:

> It  is  not  advisable to mix calls to input functions from the stdio library with low-level calls to read(2) for the file descriptor associated with the input stream; the results will be undefined and very probably not what you want.

Here is a `fgets()` version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LEN 20

char *strip(char *s) {
    size_t n = strlen(s);
    if(n && s[n-1] == '\n') s[n-1] = '\0';
    return s;
}

int main() {
    char color[LEN];
    char pluraNoun[LEN];
    char celebrity[LEN];

    printf("Enter a color: ");
    fgets(color, LEN, stdin);

    printf("Enter a plural noun: ");
    fgets(pluraNoun, LEN, stdin);

    printf("Enter a celebrity: ");
    fgets(celebrity, LEN, stdin);

    printf("Roses are %s\n", strip(color));
    printf("%s are blue\n", strip(pluraNoun));
    printf("I love %s\n", strip(celebrity));
    return 0;
}
```

You want check the return value from `fgets()` to ensure your program does something sensible on `EOF`.

Comment: So a string before should be without any whitespace around it to make fgets work?

Comment: `fgets()` reads a line including the newline (that you need in usual line buffered terminal mode) but at most size -1 bytes and ends it with '\0' (so it's a proper string).  `strip()` function just removes the newline if there is one otherwise your output format will change.

Comment: thanks man, it helped a lot to understand what's going on there